# Two divs, one under another, one dynamic and second fill the rest of space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div 500x500.

I need to create two divs indside that div, one above another. One of top have to be dynamic, with height based on content text. Second one have to fill the rest of space, and have dynamic image based on size of that div, while keeping aspect ratio. Anybody knows how to achieve that? I think this is impossible using only css, so if you have any propositions to resolve this problem with javascript, then I will be very greatfull.

Examples:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: This is a decent question, but you may want to include some of what you've already tried that hasn't worked and explain where it went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think having a fixed height and width of parent will cause the child elements to overflow.

Here is the JsFiddle [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0w7g8rsg/1/) with dynamic height and width of parent which works as per your expectation.

```css
.parent{
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:2em;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child{
  height:auto;
}

#child1{
  flex:1;
   background-color:red;
   padding:0.5em;
}

#child2{
  flex:1;
   background-color:blue;
   padding:1em 1.5em;
   text-align:center;
}

#child2 img{
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child" id="child1">
   sometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometest
   sometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometest
   sometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometest sometest sometestsometestsometest sometest 
   </div>
   <div class="child" id="child2">
     <img src=""/>
   </div>
</div>
```

However you can also have static height and width as you have stated in this case you will have to set the overflow property of parent to auto.

Try the solution an let me know if you require something else.

Comment: Thanks! This is closest answer, but still image is not resisable. I just added image container with 100% height and width, and image with max-height and max-width 100% inside.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7n1Lrkty/

Answer (score 0):

All of this is entirely possible through CSS. It will take some fidgeting around with the property `flex`. Here is the best tutorial/explanation around for how to use `flex` correctly.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

As for making sure your image height is relative to the parent `div` you would just need to define some percentage height on the image and the width will scale automatically.

E.g.

Give `display: flex` to the outside container. You can then define a constant height for your first element and give `flex: 1` to your second element. This will make the second element grow to the empty space. Your image will still resize accordingly.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Added more to better explain. Cool?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $("#inside").width($("#inside").height());
})
```

```css
div{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
div div{
  margin: 10px;
}
#outside{
  background: rgb(200,200,50);
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#top{
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
}
#bottom{ 
  background: rgb(0,100,100);
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#inside{
  background: rgb(0,200,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outside">
  <div id="top">
    content here <br>
    asdf<br>
    asdf<br>
    asdf<br>
    adsf<br>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div id="inside">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```